# Rust - Is the stack size different for debug vs. release mode?

Tags: rust, stack-size

Consider the following program:

```
fn recursive_call(x: u32) -> u32 {
    println!("x: {:?}", x);
    recursive_call(x +1)
}

fn main() {
    recursive_call(0);
}
```

When I run `cargo build && ./target/debug/recursive_call`, this crashes after `x: 58152`:

```
x: 58152

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
Aborted (core dumped)
```

while when I run  `cargo build --release && ./target/release/recursive_call`, this crashes only after `x: 104728`:

```
x: 104728

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
[...]
```

I wondering where this difference in behavior comes from? Is the stack size different in release vs. debug mode? Or is this because of some compile time optimizations I am missing (if so, what would so optimizations be?)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, [according to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G4W984) on x86-64 the reserved stacksize for the function in debug mode is 120 bytes, with optimizations turned on (`-O`) it is 72 bytes. That is quite normal.

Answer (score 0):

The stack size is the same for debug and release (and unless you have threads, the stack size is actually fixed by the OS, see eg. `ulimit -s` on Linux). However the stack *usage* may be different because in debug mode the compiler adds some data to each stack frame to help debuggers find local variables.

Note that [tail-call optimization may cause the compiler to remove the recursion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/271#issuecomment-271161622) and allow an infinite loop in release mode.